# How to efficently link these db columns

Tags: sql, database, database-design

First of all if this should maybe be in the code review section or somewhere else please let me know.

I am trying to build a db schema and I've come to a bit of a sticky patch. I want three types of accounts SINGLE, ORGANISATION & MULTI. I need to figure out where logins should be against. Most likely a club and organisation

A SINGLE account will allow one club to register and manage club details.

An ORGANISATION account will allow you to register many clubs. At the organisation level you should be able to see all the clubs and their members. At a club level you can control only your own club details and your own members.

Finally a MULTI (the tricky bit, for me at least). This account will allow you to register multiple organisations and multiple clubs against these or even single clubs. Again the top level will show all organisations and their clubs and stand alone clubs.

As you can see from my schema the single accounts have only the one club each. The organsiation have many clubs. The Multi can have organisations and clubs.

In the example below I want account 4 to have 2 stand along clubs and an organisation which has 3 clubs.

```
ACCOUNTS
==============
id, name, type (single, organisation, multi)
1 | Single Account 1        | SINGLE
2 | Single Account 2        | SINGLE
3 | Org Account 1           | ORGANISATION
4 | Multi Org Account 1 | MULTI


CLUBS
==============
id, account_id, organisation_id, name
1  | 1 | (NULL)     | Single Club 1
2  | 2 | (NULL)     | Single Club 1
3  | 3 | 1            | Org 1 Club 1
4  | 3 | 1            | Org 1 Club 2
5  | 3 | 1            | Org 1 Club 2
6  | 4 | 2            | (Multi) Org 2 Club 1
7  | 4 | 2            | (Multi) Org 2 Club 2
8  | 4 | 3            | (Multi) Org 2&3 Club 3
9  | 4 | 3            | (Multi) Org 2&3 Club 4
10 | 4 | 3            | (Multi) Org 2&3 Club 5


ORGANISATIONS
==============
id, account_id, organisation_id, name
1 | 3 | (NULL) | ORG 1
2 | 4 | (NULL) | ORG 2
3 | 4 | 2        | ORG 3


MEMBERS
==============
id, club_id, name
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is the best I could think of...

```
create table account (
   account_id int unsigned primary key,
   account_name varchar(20) not null, 
   is_org tinyint(1) unsigned not null,
   parent_account_id int unsigned
);

create table club (
   club_id int unsigned auto_increment primary key,
   club_name varchar(20) not null,
   account_id int unsigned,
   foreign key (account_id) references account(account_id)
);

insert into account values (1, 'multi', 0, null); 

insert into account values (2, 'm org 1', 1, 1); 
insert into account values (3, 'm org 2', 1, 1);

insert into account values (4, 'org', 1, null); 

insert into club values (null, 'disco lemonade', null); 

insert into club values (null, 'billy club', 1); 

insert into club values (null, 'm o 1 club A', 2); 

insert into club values (null, 'm o 2 club A', 3); 
insert into club values (null, 'm o 2 club B', 3); 

insert into club values (null, 'o club A', 4); 
insert into club values (null, 'o club B', 4); 


select p.account_name as parent_name,
       a.account_name, 
       c.club_name 

from   account as a 

       left outer join account as p
         on p.account_id=a.parent_account_id

       /* a right outer join is generally bad practice, btw, 
          but you should get the point                        */
       right outer join club as c  
         on c.account_id=a.account_id;

/*
+-------------+--------------+----------------+
| parent_name | account_name | club_name      |
+-------------+--------------+----------------+
| NULL        | NULL         | disco lemonade |
| NULL        | multi        | billy club     |
| multi       | m org 1      | m o 1 club A   |
| multi       | m org 2      | m o 2 club A   |
| multi       | m org 2      | m o 2 club B   |
| NULL        | org          | o club A       |
| NULL        | org          | o club B       |
+-------------+--------------+----------------+
*/



select a.parent_account_id,
       p.account_name as parent_name,

       a.account_id,
       a.account_name,
       a.is_org,

       c.club_id, 
       c.club_name 

from   account as a 

       left outer join account as p
         on p.account_id=a.parent_account_id

       join club as c 
         on c.account_id=a.account_id

where  p.account_id=1 or a.account_id=1;

/*
+-------------------+-------------+------------+--------------+--------+---------+--------------+
| parent_account_id | parent_name | account_id | account_name | is_org | club_id | club_name    |
+-------------------+-------------+------------+--------------+--------+---------+--------------+
|              NULL | NULL        |          1 | multi        |      0 |       2 | billy club   |
|                 1 | multi       |          2 | m org 1      |      1 |       3 | m o 1 club A |
|                 1 | multi       |          3 | m org 2      |      1 |       4 | m o 2 club A |
|                 1 | multi       |          3 | m org 2      |      1 |       5 | m o 2 club B |
+-------------------+-------------+------------+--------------+--------+---------+--------------+
*/
```

I assume a multi and organization are inherently different than a club and that you need to store more info (columns) about a club than the other things.  If this is not the case, you can just use one table and go full hierarchical on it all... or you could use a `club_details` table or something.

```
create table thing (
   thing_id int unsigned primary key,
   thing_name varchar(20), 
   thing_type char(1), 
   parent_id int unsigned 
); 

insert into thing values (1,  'multi',   'm', null); 
insert into thing values (2,  'm org 1', 'o', 1); 
insert into thing values (3,  'm org 2', 'o', 1); 
insert into thing values (4,  'org',     'o', null); 

insert into thing values (5,  'disco lemonade', 'c', null);  
insert into thing values (6,  'billy club',     'c', 1);  
insert into thing values (7,  'm o 1 club A',   'c', 2);  
insert into thing values (8,  'm o 2 club A',   'c', 3); 
insert into thing values (9,  'm o 2 club B',   'c', 3);  
insert into thing values (10, 'o club A',       'c', 4); 
insert into thing values (11, 'o club B',       'c', 4); 


select   p2.thing_name as grand_parent_name, 
         p2.thing_type as grand_parent_type,

         p1.thing_name as parent_name, 
         p1.thing_type as parent_type,

         club.thing_name as club_name

from     thing as club

         left outer join thing as p1
            on p1.thing_id=club.parent_id  

         left outer join thing as p2
            on p2.thing_id=p1.parent_id  

where    club.thing_type='c'


/*
+-------------------+-------------------+-------------+-------------+----------------+
| grand_parent_name | grand_parent_type | parent_name | parent_type | club_name      |
+-------------------+-------------------+-------------+-------------+----------------+
| NULL              | NULL              | NULL        | NULL        | disco lemonade |
| NULL              | NULL              | multi       | m           | billy club     |
| multi             | m                 | m org 1     | o           | m o 1 club A   |
| multi             | m                 | m org 2     | o           | m o 2 club A   |
| multi             | m                 | m org 2     | o           | m o 2 club B   |
| NULL              | NULL              | org         | o           | o club A       |
| NULL              | NULL              | org         | o           | o club B       |
+-------------------+-------------------+-------------+-------------+----------------+
*/
```

Comment: Yes I think this is along the lines of what I am looking. Will still need play about as it has the potential to get very messy

Comment: @PierceMcGeough - I'm bored.  Give me some potential use cases or extended examples of messy things and I will do proof of concept stuff.  You can have one table for multi, org, and club.  In the club table, have a owner_id or something, which links to org or multi or null.  Anyway you do it, if a member is tied to a multi, you will need to check org and club levels to show what they should have access to.

Answer (score 0):

Am not sure if you are asking how to design the tables for it. Well your sample data shows the relationship between entities. So Club will have a foreign key to both organization and account (I assume one club can only be a part of 1 organization/1 account, else we will need a bridge table to accommodate many to many relationship). Organization will have a foreign key to account. Also I don't understand the need of having a separate organization_id column in the organization table.

## ORGANISATIONS

id, account_id, organisation_id, name

1 | 3 | (NULL) | ORG 1

2 | 4 | (NULL) | ORG 2

3 | 4 | 2      | ORG 3

What does the organization_id mean here?

Comment: Here an organisation can belong to a larger organisation. So i guess its more a parent id maybe